# Why this interface casting does not work?

Tags: java, interface, casting

I need a little bit of help on how to work correctly with java interfaces.

I have an ArrayList with the implementation of a certain interface.

```
private ArrayList<ServiceClassImpl> services;
```

The manager class also implements an interface in which is a method who should return an ArrayList with the interface of the ServiceClass Impl

```
@Override
public List<IService> getAllServices() {
    return this.services;
}
```

Problem is that this does not work and I dont know why. With a single object it does work.

```
private ServiceClassImpl service;


public IService getService() {
       return this.service;
}
```

I don't understand it. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: If you change the method return type to `List<? extends IService>` it should work, assuming such a change is compatible with how other code consumes this API. The other option is to make `services` a `List<IService>` instead. But for more information on why your code doesn't work, see the duplicate.

Comment: A `List<IService>` is something you'd be able to add a `FancyServiceImpl` to, if `FancyServiceImpl` implements `IService`.  But you can't do that with an `ArrayList<ServiceClassImpl>`.  Therefore, an `ArrayList<ServiceClassImpl>` is not a `List<IService>`, so you can't return `this.services` from a method whose return type is `List<IService>`.